# How could I handle empty json body with Combine (AnyPublisher)?

Tags: swift, combine

Given this publisher where i handle response with body. Than I can decode to a User struct. It works well.

```
// Wrapped Request, return with an URLRequest object with POST method
let request = RequestWithModel(networkMethod: .post, path: PathBuilder().user().build(), model: User(userId: 1, title: "fokora", body: "baroka")).urlRequest()

let addUser : AnyPublisher<User, Error> = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
.map{ $0.data }
.decode(type: User.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

How can I handle response when it comes empty json body, but I want to know about its success (status code is 200)? What kind of publisher do I need to use?

```
// Wrapped Request, return with an URLRequest object with DELETE method
let request = RequestWithoutModel(networkMethod: .delete, path: PathBuilder().user().id(id: "1").build()).urlRequest()
let deleteUser : AnyPublisher<... no need this ..., Error> = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
.map{ $0.data }
.decode(type: ... no need this ..., decoder: JSONDecoder()) // no need to decode anything at all
.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only care about the response, you should `map` the `response` property instead of `data`. If you want to check the response code as well, you should cast `response` to `HTTPURLResponse`.

```
let deleteUser = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
    .compactMap { $0.response as? HTTPURLResponse }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

This will result in a publisher of type `AnyPublisher<HTTPURLResponse, URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Failure>`.

If you only need the status code, you can call `.map(\.statusCode)` after the `compactMap` - or change the body of the `compactMap` to `($0 as? HTTPURLResponse).statusCode`, which will result in a publisher whose output is of type `Int` instead of `HTTPURLResponse`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I closed this thread but I just asked a similar question on this topic (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63456569)! If you could take a look, please! Thanks in advance!